# Terminate method in second middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I use two middlewares (Laravel 5.2):

```
'api' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateApi::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\UserUpdate::class,
],
```

In first middleware I don't return next request but this:

```
return response()->json([
        'error' => [
        'status' => 401,
        'message' => 'Unauthorized',
    ],
], 401, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

In UserUpdate I use terminate function. Method "handle" is not called (what is expected) but terminate is.

Do you know why?

Comment: In middleware you should always return next request. Middlewares are like pipes. If returned something other than next request, it will terminate.

Comment: IMO it's not true, you can return something else. Check example in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware Next middleware is executed when you return request from previous one. In my question "handle" in second middleware is not executed (expected) but terminate is and I don't understand why.

Comment: Imagine that in your case middlewares are working so: `\App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateApi::handle($request, function () {
\App\Http\Middleware\UserUpdate::handle($request);
})`. If you don't have next callback in first middleware, second one will be terminated

Comment: Ok, all clear. Thanks.